# where is bake option under render properties in blender 2.9.3

Tags: baking

I was following a tutorial where I need to bake shadows however there is no bake option in my version and its just indirect lighting and I do not know how do I bake shadows with that.
[image: tutorial]
[image: my screen]

Answer (score 1):

You can't bake in Eevee, you need to switch to Cycles:

[image]